# How to change the default (system-wide) content of the "dock"-like favorites in Xfce?

Tags: linux, xfce, alma-linux

Have a minimal installation of **AlmaLinux 9.1** and also installed the group **Xfce**. Here is no menus, nothing just the top-bar. When pressing the <kbd>WIN</kbd> key, got this screen. I'm happy with it, just need some tweaking.

Questions:

- what is the name of that "bar of favorites", e.g. how I can google about it? (see image)
- how I can change the content for each (especially newly created) users of that "bar of favorites" thing in Xfce? (want remove the "Terminal" and the "Files" icon and want add Thunar to that "favorites")
- I prefer editing some files (probably XML?) directly from the terminal instead of the GUI...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the first of your questions... It's called a **Panel**. Info about the Xfce Panel is available at https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/start.

About making changes from the terminal, I've not done anything along those lines myself, but [how to make a script to modify xfce4 panel?](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=8619) might provide some insight.

Comment: thank you, at least now know, what to google... :D If nobody will answer the "how to change" part, will accept...